# Finding first image on google text search (on the upper block) using jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

I've used this :

```
     Elements images = doc.select("img[id^=dimg]");
     Element image = images.first();
     String url = image.absUrl("src");
```

As div.img-brk is an element represent the images block and I want to fetch the first image there.

div.img-brk img refer to the img decendents of div.img-brk.

adding the url I'm trying to get the image from. [Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=885178979613%20price&num10)

Comment: 1. It's hard to tell what's the problem without the url. 2. Disable JS in your browser and check that you can see the image. If not - the site uses JS to load the images and jsoup is no good in this case.

Comment: Hi sir, I just added the link.

Comment: and I can still see the image after disabling JS.

Comment: It's funny - when I disable the JS I don't see the images, I see only the frame... Anyway - the selector is `[id^="dimg"]` but it has some base64 encoded data.

Comment: Interesting, maybe because useragent may differ..

Comment: I've tried and still no success, what I saw is that when I disable JS the tagging differ, the img element changed attribute from id to class. (I'm not familiar with JS so much so maybe it's standard behavior)